# Overload operator++ for encapsulated standard container

Tags: c++, containers

I am encapsulating a std::list to make it safely iterable when iterating can potentially mark contents as 'invalid', and 'invalid' contents are skipped in the iteration.  Specifically, during the iteration the current object could schedule itself or other objects for removal from the list and mark those objects as invalid.  The list is then periodically cleaned of invalid objects.

**How do I define an increment operator to make range-based for loops work correctly?**  Here is my class:

```
template <typename T> class DeferredCleanupList
{
public:
    DeferredCleanupList() {
        (void)static_cast<Valid *>((T)0);
    }
    virtual ~DeferredCleanupList() {}

    typedef typename std::list<T>::iterator iterator;

    iterator begin() {
        iterator it = container.begin();

        if ((*it)->valid())
            return it;

        return next(it);
    }
    iterator next(iterator it) {
        do {
            ++it;
        }
        while (it != end() && !(*it)->valid());

        return it;
    }
    iterator end() { return container.end(); }

//    to be implemented:
//    typedef typename std::list<T>::const_iterator const_iterator ;
//    const_iterator cbegin() const { return container.cbegin(); }
//    const_iterator cend() const { return container.cend(); }
//    const_iterator cnext() const { ??? }

    size_t size() const { return container.size(); }

    void add(T *ptr) { container.push_front(ptr); }
    void remove(T *ptr) { ptr->invalidate(); }

    // called occasionally
    void delete_invalid() {
        for (auto it = container.begin(); it != container.end(); ) {
            auto ptr = *it;
            if (ptr->valid())
                ++it;
            else {
                delete ptr;
                it = container.erase(it);
            }
        }
    }

private:
    DeferredCleanupList(const DeferredCleanupList&);
    DeferredCleanupList& operator=(const DeferredCleanupList&);

    std::list<T> container;
};
```

My current test case is something like:

```
int main() {
    class D : public Valid {};

    DeferredCleanupList<D *> list;

    for (auto it = list.begin(); it != list.end(); it = list.next(it)); // works
    for (auto ptr : list); // iterates, but doesn't call list.next(it)
}
```

EDIT:
After some trial and error, I wrote this iterator wrapper based on the suggestions in the comments:

```
template <typename T> class DeferredCleanupList
{
public:
    class iterator {
    public:
        iterator(typename std::list<T>::iterator it, DeferredCleanupList<T>& ls) : it(it), list(ls) {}

        iterator& operator=(const iterator& rhs) { it = rhs; return *this; }
        iterator& operator++() {
            do {
                ++it;
            }
            while (it != list.end().it && !(*it)->valid());

            return *this;
        }
        friend bool operator==(const iterator& lhs, const iterator& rhs) { return lhs.it == rhs.it; }
        friend bool operator!=(const iterator& lhs, const iterator& rhs) { return !(lhs == rhs); }

        T& operator*() { return *it; }

    private:
        typename std::list<T>::iterator it;
        DeferredCleanupList& list;
    };

    iterator begin() {
        iterator it = iterator(container.begin(), *this);

        if (it == end() || (*it)->valid())
            return it;

        return ++it;
    }

    iterator end() { return iterator(container.end(), *this); }
}
```

It appears to work perfectly in all the test cases I throw at it.  Am I missing anything obvious with this approach?  Is there a more elegant solution?

Comment: With `typedef typename std::list<T>::iterator iterator;` there's no way to override the preincrement operator since the compiler can't distinguish between your container's iterator and the standard list iterator.  You'll need to make a wrapper class which stores a list iterator internally, but then redefines the preincrement operator - which as a method of the new class would need to look like `iterator& operator++()`.

Comment: Also, incidentally, it looks like the current implementation of `begin()` will probably crash if you try to execute it on an empty container (i.e. the underlying `std::list<T>` is empty).

Comment: Good catch on the begin() crash.  I updated my question with the solution I came up with based on your suggestion.  It works nicely, I just wish there was a simpler solution.

Comment: Boost provides a `boost::iterators::filter_iterator` template class which does a lot of what you did in your solution, only more generally.  Using that instead of rolling your own might make things a bit simpler and easier to read.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not do it within the container class. You should implement your own iterator and implement the behavior you want in it's prefix increment operator. You can do it several ways including **inheriting** one from **STL** or creating your own wrapper for **std::list** iterator.

Actually to implement your desired behavior in iterator you need to provide to your custom iterator class **the end iterator** of container.

I would not recommend you to implement your own iterators unless your design actually good with them. Unnecessary complications almost always lead to even more unnecessary complications.

I've modified your code so it actually compiles and implemented **std::list** iterator wrapper to behave as you planned.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <list>
#include <iterator>

using namespace std;

class Valid {};

template<typename _Tp>
struct myIteratorWrapper
{

  typedef myIteratorWrapper<_Tp>         _Self;
  typedef _Tp               value_type;
  typedef _Tp*                 pointer;
  typedef _Tp&               reference;

  typedef typename std::list<_Tp>::iterator listIterator;

  listIterator it;
  listIterator itEnd;

  myIteratorWrapper(const listIterator& listIterArg) _GLIBCXX_NOEXCEPT
    : it(listIterArg)
  {}

  myIteratorWrapper(const listIterator& itBegin,
            const listIterator& itEnd) _GLIBCXX_NOEXCEPT
    : it(itBegin), itEnd(itEnd)
  {}

  reference
  operator*() const _GLIBCXX_NOEXCEPT
  { return *it; }

  pointer
  operator->() const _GLIBCXX_NOEXCEPT
  { return &(*it); }

  /* Change logic of this method as you wish, but keep the signature */ 
  _Self&
  operator++() _GLIBCXX_NOEXCEPT
  {
    do
    {
      ++it;
    }while (it != itEnd && !(*it)->valid());

    return *this;
  }

  bool
  operator==(const _Self& __x) const _GLIBCXX_NOEXCEPT
  { return it == __x.it; }

  bool
  operator!=(const _Self& __x) const _GLIBCXX_NOEXCEPT
  { return it != __x.it; }
};

template <typename T> class DeferredCleanupList
{
public:
  DeferredCleanupList() {
    (void)static_cast<Valid *>((T)0);
  }
  virtual ~DeferredCleanupList() {}

  typedef myIteratorWrapper<T> iterator;

  iterator begin() {
    iterator it(container.begin(), container.end());
    return it;
  }

  iterator next(iterator it) {       
    return ++it;
  }

  iterator end() { return container.end(); }

  size_t size() const { return container.size(); }

  void add(T ptr) { container.push_front(ptr); }
  void remove(T ptr) { ptr->invalidate(); }

  // called occasionally
  void delete_invalid() {
    for (auto it = container.begin(); it != container.end(); ) {
      auto ptr = *it;
      if (ptr->valid())
    ++it;
      else {
    delete ptr;
    it = container.erase(it);
      }
    }
  }

private:
  DeferredCleanupList(const DeferredCleanupList&);
  DeferredCleanupList& operator=(const DeferredCleanupList&);

  std::list<T> container;
};

class D : public Valid {
  bool isValid;
  std::string myName;
public:

  D(std::string myName, bool arg = false)
    : myName(myName), isValid(arg) {}

  bool valid() const
  { return isValid; }

  const std::string& whoAmI() const
  { return myName; }
};

int main() {
  D o1("o1", true);
  D o2("o2");
  D o3("o3", true);
  D o4("o4");
  D o5("o5", true);

  DeferredCleanupList<D *> list;
  list.add(&o1);
  list.add(&o2);
  list.add(&o3);
  list.add(&o4);
  list.add(&o5);

  for (auto ptr : list)
    {
      std::cout << ptr->whoAmI() << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Output:

```
o5
o3
o1
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  I’m going to go ahead and accept this because it completely answers the question of HOW to implement a solution.  However, I had already come up with a solution in my edits that, as far as I can tell, is very similar to this.  Would you mind pointing out any significant shortcomings in my solution that yours covers?

Answer (score 0):

From http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for

> The above syntax produces code equivalent to the following (__range,
>   __begin and __end are for exposition only):
>
> ```
> {
>     auto && __range = range_expression ; 
>     for (auto __begin = begin_expr, __end = end_expr; 
>             __begin != __end; ++__begin) { 
>         range_declaration = *__begin; 
>     loop_statement 
>     } 
> }
> ```

ie you must have the preincrement operator defined.

Comment: Yes, but how do I do that within the class?  And more importantly, how to call the default preincrement operator from within the operator++ definition?  I'll put what I'm trying in the question.

Comment: the post increment operator returns a COPY of what it was; and then increases itself.  This means it won't return a reference but a value.  The pre increment however increases itself by one and then returns a reference to itself.  This it has the signature ` T& T::operator++();`